# Get all values of specific key with xpath (python web scraping)

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, web-scraping

Suppose we have web page

```
<div class="specific-row" data-id="101736782"></div>
<div class="yellow-box-row" data-id="112376244"></div>
<div class="specific-row" data-id="179218312"></div>
<div class="vip-row" data-id="123749014"></div>
```

How can I get all **data-id** values? 
Like  `['101736782', '112376244', '179218312', '123749014']`

I used tree.xpath

```
import requests
from lxml import html

r = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

tree.xpath("//div@data-id=['any']")
```

Comment: XPath 2.0 solution would be `string-join(//@data-id,";")` in combination with Saxon/C processor for Python. Output : `101736782;112376244;179218312;123749014`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try this...

```py
from lxml import etree, html

doc = '<root><div class="specific-row" data-id="101736782"></div><div class="yellow-box-row" data-id="112376244"></div><div class="specific-row" data-id="179218312"></div><div class="vip-row" data-id="123749014"></div></root>'

root = etree.XML(doc) # EQUALS TO >>> root = html.fromstring(doc)

xpatheval = etree.XPathEvaluator(root)

divs = xpatheval('//div')
ids = [el.get('data-id') for el in divs]

## If you have installed cssselect you can do

divs = root.cssselect('[data-id]')
ids = [el.get('data-id') for el in divs]

# (cssselect) use the same schema of selection of 'some_element_node.querySelector("data-id")' of browsers

# Maybe this is what you are looking for -- https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elementpath
root.findall('div[@data-id]')
```

I use this [link](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) to help me.

Comment: Hi Daniel.Thanks for answering, it really works. I tried using attrib method and is also works: `ids=[]
for atag in tree.xpath("//div[@id='results']/div"):
  try:
    #print(atag.attrib['data-id'])
    ids.append(atag.attrib['data-id'])
  except KeyError:
    continue`

Answer (score 0):

I tried using **attrib** method and it works:

```py
ids=[]
for atag in tree.xpath("//div[@id='results']/div"):
  try:
    #print(atag.attrib['data-id'])
    ids.append(atag.attrib['data-id'])
  except KeyError:
    continue
```