# Extracting list or dictionary from xml file

Tags: python, xml, list, dictionary

Hello I never worked with xml.. Can someone help me with creating a list or dictionary in python which gives an ID a specific name (string) from the xml file.

Here is my xml file:

api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.xml?num_rows=10000&start_row=10001&&criteria=model::Gene,rma::criteria,products[abbreviation$eq%27Mouse%27]

I can show you a snippet:

```
<Response success="true" start_row="10001" num_rows="9990" total_rows="19991">
<objects>
<object>
<acronym>Hdac4</acronym>
<alias-tags>4932408F19Rik AI047285</alias-tags>
<chromosome-id>34</chromosome-id>
<ensembl-id nil="true"/>
<entrez-id>208727</entrez-id>
<genomic-reference-update-id>491928275</genomic-reference-update-id>
<homologene-id>55946</homologene-id>
<id>84010</id>
<legacy-ensembl-gene-id nil="true"/>
<name>histone deacetylase 4</name>
<organism-id>2</organism-id>
<original-name>histone deacetylase 4</original-name>
<original-symbol>Hdac4</original-symbol>
<reference-genome-id nil="true"/>
<sphinx-id>188143</sphinx-id>
<version-status>no change</version-status>
</object>
<object>
<acronym>Prss54</acronym>
<alias-tags>4931432M23Rik Klkbl4</alias-tags>
<chromosome-id>53</chromosome-id>
<ensembl-id nil="true"/>
<entrez-id>70993</entrez-id>
<genomic-reference-update-id>491928275</genomic-reference-update-id>
<homologene-id>19278</homologene-id>
<id>46834</id>
<legacy-ensembl-gene-id nil="true"/>
<name>protease, serine 54</name>
<organism-id>2</organism-id>
<original-name>protease, serine, 54</original-name>
<original-symbol>Prss54</original-symbol>
<reference-genome-id nil="true"/>
<sphinx-id>65991</sphinx-id>
<version-status>updated</version-status>
</object>
<object>
...
```

So in the end I want to have a dictionary or list that says:
208727 is Hdac4 and that for all in my 2 xml files..

So I need the entrez ID and the original symbol.

I want to have that out of two xml files:

http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.xml?num_rows=10000&start_row=1&&criteria=model::Gene,rma::criteria,products[abbreviation$eq%27Mouse%27]

and

http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.xml?num_rows=10000&start_row=10001&&criteria=model::Gene,rma::criteria,products[abbreviation$eq%27Mouse%27]

Can someone help me with that?
I am not sure in which format I should store it.. In the end I want to search for the ID and get the original name.

Comment: You should take a look at [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the XML and extract the required information

Comment: This is far too broad/vague, and likely off-topic. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the XML stored in a file called `results.xml`

Then using BeautifulSoup is as simple as

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('results.xml') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'xml')

    final_dictionary = {}

    for object in soup.find_all('object'):
        final_dictionary[object.find('acronym').string] = object.find('entrez-id').string

    print(final_dictionary)
```

If instead, you want to retrieve XML from a URL, then that is also simple

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "<your_url>"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'xml')

# Once you have the 'soup' variable assigned
# It's the same code as above example from here on
```

Output

```sh
{'Hdac4': '208727', 'Prss54': '70993'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61494994/get-all-values-of-specific-key-with-xpath-python-web-scraping/61495237#61495237) about something close to XML and you can try use them.

Using the lib of python lxml, with docs in [link](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html)

You can start with:

```py
import requests
from lxml import etree, html
# edit: Yes, BeautfulSoup works too, like your friend say before
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.xml?num_rows=10000&start_row=10001&&criteria=model::Gene,rma::criteria,products[abbreviation$eq%27Mouse%27]"
req = requests.get(url)
doc = req.text

root = etree.XML(doc) # Works with this or ...
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc) # works with this
```

them you need read to docs to see how to navigate by tags